# What is the corrct way of running useEffect hook depending on state variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-effect

I am writing a camera app. So when the user goes to the camera page they are provided with the option to grant camera permissions or not. I am saving their decision in variable   `const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);` My current use effect function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      const audioPermissions = await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (
        cameraPermissions.status === "granted" &&
        audioPermissions.status === "granted"
      ) {
        setHasPermission(true);
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```

This currently works correctly when the user runs the app for the very first time - they grant permission, and thats it - I can use the camera!

However..... what if they dont grant permission. They ecide not to use the camera, they deny access and later on they change their mind.. For instance 5 mins later, they open the "camera" page again and want to grant a permission. Here is my problem. As it is in the current situation `useEffect`, i.e. the request to use the camera will show only once, when you initially load the page. How do I force it to pop up again if the user hasnt granted permissions yet?

I tried the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      const audioPermissions = await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (
        cameraPermissions.status === "granted" &&
        audioPermissions.status === "granted"
      ) {
        setHasPermission(true);
      }
    })();
  }, [hasPermission === null]);
```

but it didnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: if that component doesn't remount when navigating to it 5 minutes later, then you'd need to find a way to hook to the navigation event, whatever you're using to navigate, instead of a simple `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to pass the variable that matters. No need to check anything else.

```
  }, [hasPermission]);
```

Comment: initially has permission is null; if I havent set it, it is still null, so the variable hasnt changed, hence it wont re-render

Comment: And the only place you are changing this is inside your useEffect?

Comment: yes; I want to set it on the intitial rendering of that page - if it is falce, I dont show the camrea at all, but if the user later on comes back to that page, they should have an option to reset their permissions

Comment: Isn't the hook running once more after they are coming back to the page from another page? Or you mean after minimising their browser ?

Comment: You are right. The problem is else where - for some reason it doesnt ask again for permissions. I have granted camera permissions, not audioPermissions and hence it messes up

Comment: If user is coming navigating to another page and coming back, the component should be mounted again.